# SQL Developer not fetching rows for views

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer Version `4.0.3.16` and JDK Version Java(TM) Platform `1.7.0_71`, (OS Windows 7)

When I am executing a query as `select * from table_name`, the query is fetching rows.

But if I try to fetch the rows from a view `select * from view_name` the query is fetching 0 results even if the view is pulling records.

This I have confirmed by running the same query in **different machine** with **same db connection**.

What could be possibly wrong with settings in my machine.
I have tried by completely deleting the  `\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper` folder and running the SQL developer again, deleting and creating the new connections.

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: *This I have confirmed by running the same query in different machine with same db connection* You mean you could see the SQL query result on another client connecting to same database? What do you see in the query result? Does it say **no rows returned** if you execute it as script?

Comment: Yes,  I can see the query results on another client connecting to same database.It fetched rows of the view . In my machine I just get the message that 0 rows fetched.Moreover If I run the query as script it shows 'no rows selected' .

Comment: Are you sure the database connection is same and you are not connecting to different schema or a different database altogether?

Comment: Can you execute it in SQL*Plus and confirm?

Comment: Yes I am quite sure about the database connection and schema.I can try running it in SQL *Plus

Comment: Please confirm on SQL*Plus from the same machine you got problem with

Comment: Are you attempting to `select` from the same schema? Are all underlying table permissions for the view correct?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a session with uncommitted changes being used to check that the view gives the required data, whereas all other session cannot see the change.

Answer (score 1):

The NLS setting answer worked for me. I checked the 'skip NLS settings' box, ran the same query again, and this time I got the table rows. Prior to changing the NLS settings, I was getting empty rows when I queried on a certain table in a schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago trying to bring up a view.  I prefixed the view with the schema.  That worked for me.  Hope this helps.

```
select * from schema.view;
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be two possibilities.

1. you have to check read access is granted for you or not.
2. Recompile your view and check.
   Because what happens sometimes we delete some columns from the tables which we are using in the view.it means that now the view is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Reset or enable check box your NLS setting at your SQL developer > Preferences > Database > NLS

Comment: This actually works. OP has already mentioned that it works on other machine. Open another sql-tab after skipping this in Preferences. http://nageswararaoboya.blogspot.com/2018/01/hroperatingunits-table-data-in-oracle.html

Answer (score 0):

This is latest Java installed in your PC or laptop. Uninstall latest JDK and install jre-7u65-windows-i586.exe. It should work perfectly fine. I had same issue and

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).